# Design pattern for encapsulating custom filter in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am designing a module, which gets large amount of data in JSON format in a queue. Now a user can provide a filter, and the module should be able to return all the elements which matches with filter condition.

The data is in a key value format, in that I dont know the name of the fields beforehand, but its the part of the data itself. Something like this -

```
metrics-list -
         metrics: [
            {
                key: name,
                actual-metrics-values: {
                   String : Float
                }  
            }
]
```

Now I am planning the filter object should have the following sort of structure -

```
Class Filter {
   String Name;
   String filterCondition;
   Metrics[] apply();
}
```

the big problem is how to store the filterCondition, such that I can just apply it over the data set and get the metrics which matches the conditions. An example would be - I get data like this -

```
 metrics: [
            {
                key: blah1
                actual-metrics-values: {
                   a : 10.0,
                   b : 5.0
                }  
            },
             {
                key: blah2
                actual-metrics-values: {
                   a : 7.0,
                   b : 3.0
                }  
            }
]
```

and the filter is something like- a > 7.0 && b <= 7.0 which should return blah1 as the only matching metric.

Comment: The new lambda expressions functionality in Java 8 springs to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that you want to parse filter logic from a string entered by a user. This will get very involved very fast. If you can keep your filters in Java code them lambda expressions or Guava Predicate class will do the trick.

**UPDATE**

I think that getting "free form" user provided filters to work even with an existent expression parsing libraries will take a lot of engineering effort. I encourage you to consider providing users with set number of filters in the UI and map them to filtering Java code.

[Java ScriptEnginge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) does seam like the right way to go for similar problems. From documentation:

> Some useful characteristics of scripting languages are... Application extension/customization: You can "externalize" parts of your application - like configuration scripts, business logic/rules and math expressions for financial applications.

This [site](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/0720__Script-Engines.htm) has more examples.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly my concern. I want the user to provide a filter somehow, and I am not sure if there is an easier way than to let them pass the condition via string. Any ideas, on how should I get the filter condition from the user ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to implement such filter is embed expression in scripting language, for example in JavaScript and then evaluate it using ScriptEngine.

Comment: I like the sound of it, can you please eloborate on it or provide some link as to why it is easier to do this on a scripting language than on java ? Thanks.

Comment: You can dynamically add scripts, you can even store them in database as strings, users can edit such filters in ui.